# How to get length, height of object (image) in android camera?

Tags: android, camera, measurement

I am new to camera and I want to get the length and height of original object using android camera. I tried on below code:

```
double d22 = angle_of_top_object;
double d12 = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(d22));
Log.d("angle", roll_angle + "");
double d23 = 15 * d12;
tv.setText("Length:"+new DecimalFormat("##.####").format(d23)+" cm ");
Toast.makeText(CameraTestActivity.this, tv.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Log.i("Length", tv.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Do you know how far the object is from your lens?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this and get the values like this...
You just

**add your view Name like Imageview,TextView,etc**...

```
int ht = viewName..getLayoutParams().height;
int ht = viewName..getLayoutParams().width;
```

Comment: i want original objects length and height